# $('check1').attr('checked','true') not work inside ajax success function

Tags: javascript, ajax

please give me the solution of my problem:

```
$('#check0').attr('checked','true');   //it work
var idx=12;
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'get_list.php',
   data: 'id='+idx,
   cache: false,
   success: function(){
       alert('success');     //it work fine
       $('#check1').attr('checked','true');   //not work
       $('#no1').val('222222');    //it work too
   }
});
```

I tried putting `$ ('check1'). attr ('checked', 'true')` to the ajax function success but unfortunately does not work properly, but if I put the code outside of the ajax function it works fine .... there may be something wrong with the above code?.

why only the checkbox that does not work? .. while alerts and passing text to text input works well, and I am sure `check1` really exist .. it makes my already 2 hour stop working ..

Comment: Is it even going into the `success` block?

Comment: First, it should be `$('#check1').prop('checked', true)`, but that probably won't make a difference. Are you sure the AJAX is successful?

Comment: Get chrome (or Firebug) and open the Developer Tools, watch the outcome of the network tab to check that the POST is completing successfully. Next put a break point in the success method to check the callback is being called at all.

Comment: yes, AJAX works well and successfully. if I try to give a message alert on his success function it works well. I've tried using. prop ('checked', true) but the same does not work.

Comment: Post relevant HTML code please

Answer (score 0):

your ajax's success method is not getting executed, your code is ok. check this fiddle to see the result.

http://jsfiddle.net/U4wS4/1/

```
$('#check0').attr('checked',true);   //it work
var idx = 12;
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   data: 'id='+idx,
   success: function(){
       $('#check1').attr('checked',true);   //not work
   }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In ajax success you are using

```
$('#check1')
```

you haven't posted your HTML But I think you wanted this in ajax success function

```
$('#check0')
```